# How to make my sitemap.xml open in the browser instead of trying to download the file?

Tags: xml, mime-types, sitemap

My site is on SharePoint 2013 and I have tried to change the MIME type for XML to both of the following:

```
xml         application/xml
xml         text/xml
```

[image]

**Preferred result (just opens in the browser):** https://www.apple.com/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link describes all of the ways for allowing a file to be viewed by the browser instead of downloading: http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/04/open-pdf-files-in-browser.html

And also please check in which library your Xml is stored... in that library go to advanced library setting then check file opening option, there are few two few ddl like open in browser, open in client. Select open in browser and try again.... and also you can try deactivating file opening in client feature as well.

Comment: Thanks method 1 worked!• Go to SharePoint Central Administration > Application Management > Manage Web Applications
• Select the row of your web application
• Click General Settings in the ribbon
• Scroll down to Browser File Handling and select Permissive
• Click Ok